# Cancelling a Postgres insert if a value already exists in a column

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, insert

so I'm trying to only run a PostgreSQL insert in a Node.js file if there isn't a row that exists in the table that contains a specific value...

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, ["default", value2, value3, value4, value5], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
});
```

Essentially, I'm trying to only insert into the table if there is NOT any row in the table with value2 as the value of its col2. Is this possible?

UPDATE:

The error when I'm using ON CONFLICT looks like:

```
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356493+00:00 app[web.1]: error: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356494+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356494+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356495+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356496+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356497+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356498+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356498+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356498+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356499+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356499+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 148,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356500+00:00 app[web.1]: severity: 'ERROR',
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356500+00:00 app[web.1]: code: '42P10',
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356500+00:00 app[web.1]: detail: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356501+00:00 app[web.1]: hint: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356501+00:00 app[web.1]: position: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356501+00:00 app[web.1]: internalPosition: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356501+00:00 app[web.1]: internalQuery: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356502+00:00 app[web.1]: where: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356502+00:00 app[web.1]: schema: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356502+00:00 app[web.1]: table: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356503+00:00 app[web.1]: column: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356503+00:00 app[web.1]: dataType: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356503+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint: undefined,
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356503+00:00 app[web.1]: file: 'plancat.c',
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356503+00:00 app[web.1]: line: '835',
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356504+00:00 app[web.1]: routine: 'infer_arbiter_indexes'
2021-05-09T20:06:37.356504+00:00 app[web.1]: 
}
```

Comment: See here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) for `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: Depends on whether you want an error returned or to just suppress the operation. Either way you first must have a unique (or PK) constraint col col2. If you don not already have that then add it ; see [ADD table_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html). Then if you want the error raised do nothing more. if you want to suppress the error see comment by @AdrianKlaver. Note if you suppress the error you not receive any indication.

Comment: To add to comment from @Belayer, you are not required to create a  unique index(constraint) on the column. Doing so allows the `ON CONFLICT` to infer an index(constraint) from the table, but it also possible to create the index(constraint) as part of the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: My query looks like 'INSERT INTO featurestable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (col2, col3) DO NOTHING,' but I'm getting a weird error that I'll put in the question. Thanks for all the insight so far!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Put the entire new query and method of calling it into your question. Also unclear whether this error coming from driver(which is?/please include in question) or from the query itself? Would be clearer if you included the table schema and associated constraints in the question.